# Replace multiple occurrences using regex with brackets

Tags: regex, replace

I have a string `abc/0/def/0`

and would like to change it to this format  `abc[0].def[0]`

Also it is not always `0` can be any number

I was looking into replace using a regex

This is actually looking to convert `jsonPointer` format to `jsonPath` format

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure this is what you're looking for, as I haven't really worked with jsonPointer & jsonPath, but here goes :

```
let str = 'abc/0/def/0';

let sub = str.replace(/\/(\d)\//g, "[$1].");
sub = sub.replace(/\/(\d)/g, "[$1]");

console.log(sub); // abc[0].def[0]
```

It might not be the best solution, since I'm using two replacements here. But it works. Explanation:

The 1st replacement is matching any digit surrounded by slashes, like `/0/` in your example. It replaces the slashes with `[]` and adds the point after the second bracket. Thus `abc/0/` becomes `abc[0].` .

The 2nd replacement matches any digit with only a slash before (and no slash after). It just removes the slash and adds the brackets around the digit. This replaces `def/0` with `def[0]` .

This solution works for any digits, of course, like `abc/3/def/6` or `abc/6/def/3` .